# How to plug this type hole?

Tags: haskell

If I have a returned type of an expression/value:

```
:: Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m =>
     m (Either PDFInfoError PDFInfo)
```

How do I get the PDFInfo out of it? Perhaps more importantly, what process does one use to figure such things out. I'd like to leverage typed holes or some other process to be able to reason through these types (no pun intended) of questions on my own. Still reading through my first Haskell book, but wanting to understand how a more experienced Haskeller would solve this using tools.

Perhaps it will help to have the greater context of the problem (attempting to use a typed hole to let ghc help me find what I am missing to get the PDFInfo result so that I can call pdfInfoTitle on it):

```
module Main where

import Text.PDF.Info

main :: IO ()
main = do
  pdfInfoTitle $ _ pdfInfo "foo.pdf"
```

Comment: Do you need to _produce_ a value of that type, or to _consume_ a value of that type? I ask because, to me, "type hole" suggests produce, while "out of it" suggests consume.

Comment: I need to return a value of that type from the expression so that I can then call pdfInfoTitle on it and return that value to main

Comment: What do you mean by "return a value ... from the expression"? Again, produce or consume? "return a value" is producing, "from an expression" is consuming, so it is still unclear :-/

Comment: I'd like to take further action on the result of pdfInfoTitle once I have it and I can't get it until I can get at the PDFInfo value. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a compiling example:

```
module Main where

import Text.PDF.Info

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- pdfInfo "foo.pdf"
  case result of
    Left someError -> do
       putStrLn "Oh, no!"
       print someError
    Right info -> do
       putStrLn "OK! Got info!"
       print (pdfInfoTitle info)
```

The idea is: in your type, the monad `m` can be chosen as we wish as long as `m` belong to class `MonadIO`. `m = IO` satisfies that, so we can "run" `pdfInfo "foo.pdf"` inside `main`, much like `putStrLn "hello"` or `l <- geTLine` or any other IO action.

(Whenever you have `MonadIO m => ...`, you can always pretend that `m = IO`. They type is slightly more general than that, but keeping things simple helps intuition.)

So, we can use `result <- pdfInfo "foo.pdf"`.
Here, `result` has type whatever is inside `m`, that is `Either PDFInfoError PDFInfo`. Hence, `result` is either an error (wrapped under `Left`) or the actual info (wrapped using `Right`).

We can then use `case result of` to branch on the two possibilities, and handle them accordingly.

Comment: thanks! If I wanted to get just the title and not: Just "the title" as a result of the Right branch of logic, what do I do? I want to now take action on the actual title string.

Comment: @Joe The title has a `Maybe Text` type since it might be missing in the pdf file.  You can convert that to `Text` by providing a default title, e.g. `print (fromMaybe "No Title" (pdfInfoTitle info))`, after `import Data.Maybe`. Here, `case pdfInfoTitle info of Nothing -> .... ; Just title -> ....` would also work, as a basic alternative.

Comment: @Joe Do the same thing this answer does for `Either`: pattern match on it! `case pdfInfoTitle info of Nothing -> {- ... -}; Just title -> {- ... -}`

Comment: Next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035216/how-to-plug-this-type-hole-2